# How to design an expandable view with tableview content?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a client that would like this implemented: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BV0em.png

X expandable views each with a scrollable tableview with Y cells.
The main view is not scrollable. If i tap Drawer C then Drawer A should collapse and Drawer C should expand.

I've seen similar constructs, but not with tableviews inside, so I don't know exactly how to go around this.

What's the best approach to this?

1) A tableview with "inner" tableviews

2) Multiple customs views with a button and a tableview

3) Something other?

How would you implement this?

Thx!

Comment: nice work with drawing the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have done this type of implementation but dont carry source code with me.. still i can guide u the way i did it...
i will explain u the way i did and considering ur example image.

1. u will need 3 buttons (give them diff tags) with 3 bool flags to handle their on off state.
2. u will need 3 tableview(give them diff tags)
3. if screen height is 480 and all button height is 20, then remaining height will be 480-3*20=420.
   so this is the height of all the table view.
4. on the click event of any button ,based on clicked button tag find its associated table view .
5. set the flag value on button click and using the bool flags value decide to show and hide the table view and also the on/off image on the button.

Comment: How did you approach the animation part of this?

Comment: as per my requirements what i did was resized the table view height to 0 before closing it. on showing showed it and resized it to 420

Comment: cmd, you can apply a transform value using CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(X,Y) to translate your views. There's also scale and rotate transforms. You would want to put this inside a [UIView beginAnimation]; and [UIView endAnimation]; block. Example:  [UIView beginAnimations]; ...  myButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -30); [UIView endAnimation]; You may need to add the QuartzCore framework to your project to use the UIView begin.